# How to store data from a file into a vector of structs with vector members

Tags: c++, file, vector, input, struct

Let's say the input file contains the following, each corresponding with the four members in the struct:
0 2 54 34

1 2 43 56

4 5 32 67

So, for instance, in the first row from the input file, I would want 0 to be stored as a departureStationId, 2 to be stored as arrivalStationId, 54 to be stored as departureTime, and 34 as arrivalTime.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include "graph.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ifstream file;


  struct TrainsFile{ 
    vector<int> departureStationId;
    vector<int> arrivalStationId;
    vector<int> departureTime;
    vector<int> arrivalTime;
  };


  vector<TrainsFile> trains;//creating vector of structs here


  file.open(argv[1]);

  if (file.is_open())
 {
   //How does one use push_back() here given that I am dealing with vectors within vectors?
   while(!file.eof())
   {
    file >> departureStationId >> arrivalStationId >> departureTime >> 
    arrivalTime;
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: I recommend reconsidering the `TrainsFile` structure. I think you would be better served with `Train` structure that contained a single instance of a train and `vector<Train> trains;` Also watch out for [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stated goals and the sample data file, I think you're headed in a bad direction. It appears you want a list of trains in the file, not a list of train files. This makes the `vector`s inside `TrainsFile` go away and eliminates your problem.

With a quick re-name of the structure we get

```
struct Train
{
    int departureStationId;
    int arrivalStationId;
    int departureTime;
    int arrivalTime;
};
```

and if we move the reading of the file from

```
while(!file.eof())
{
    file >> departureStationId >> arrivalStationId >> departureTime >> arrivalTime;
}
```

to an `operator>>` overload for cleanliness

```
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream & in, Train & train)
{
    return in >> train.departureStationId 
              >> train.arrivalStationId 
              >> train.departureTime 
              >> train.arrivalTime;
}
```

we can then rewrite [the faulty while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)  to

```
Train train;
while (file >> train)
{
    trains.push_back(train);
}
```

Which will loop until a train cannot be read from the file.

Fully assembled example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Train
{
    int departureStationId;
    int arrivalStationId;
    int departureTime;
    int arrivalTime;
};

std::istream &operator >>(std::istream & in, Train & train)
{
    return in >> train.departureStationId
              >> train.arrivalStationId
              >> train.departureTime
              >> train.arrivalTime;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ifstream file;

    vector<Train> trains; //creating vector of structs here

    // strongly recommend testing argc to make sure there ID an argv[1] here
    file.open(argv[1]);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        Train train;
        while (file >> train)
        {
            trains.push_back(train);
        }
    }
}
```

Since there appears to be one train per line, an improvement to this would be [to use `std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to extract a line from the file and then [use a `std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to extract a train from the line. This will allow you to better detect and recover from a malformed file. See [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c) for a demonstration of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create new variables (for reading)

```
int departureId, arrivalId, departureT, arrivalT;
```

Inside your loop:

```
while(file >> departureId >> arrivalId>> departureT >> arrivalT)
{
        TrainsFile trainsfile;
        trainsfile.departureStationId.push_back(departureId);
        trainsfile.arrivalStationId.push_back(arrivalId);
        trainsfile.departureTime.push_back(departureT);
        trainsfile.arrivalTime.push_back(arrivalT);
        trains.push_back(trainsfile);
}//other code
```

Just need these variables to put in right object,then pushing your main vector